# ajax username checking just keep loading

Tags: php, ajax

I follow this example:

http://youhack.me/2010/05/04/username-availability-check-in-registration-form-using-jqueryphp/comment-page-1/#comments

the main different is that I change the connection to sqli

I tried to comment out the if, and this page can correctly echo 0 or 1
ajax_check_username.php

```
<?php
include 'include\connection.php';
include 'include\opendb.php';

include("Header.php"); 
//Include The Database Connection File 

if(isset($_POST['username']))//If a username has been submitted 
{
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);//Some  clean up :)

$check_for_username = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT lol_summoners_name     FROM lol_summoners WHERE lol_summoners_name = '$username'");

//Query to check if username is available or not 

if(mysqli_num_rows($check_for_username))
{
echo '1';//If there is a  record match in the Database - Not Available
}
else
{
echo '0';//No Record Found - Username is available 
}

}

?>
<?php 
//close connection
include 'include\closedb.php';
?>

//Here is the signup.php

<html>

<?php
include 'include\connection.php';
include 'include\opendb.php';

// include("Header.php"); 
 ?>
<head>
<title>Sign up</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"               type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()//When the dom is ready 
{
$("#username").change(function() 
{ //if theres a change in the username textbox

var username = $("#username").val();//Get the value in the username textbox
if(username.length > 3)//if the lenght greater than 3 characters
{
$("#availability_status").html('<img src="loader.gif"   align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');
//Add a loading image in the span id="availability_status"

$.ajax({  //Make the Ajax Request
type: "POST",  
url: "ajax_check_username.php",  //file name
data: "username="+ username,  //data
success: function(server_response){  

   $("#availability_status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request){ 

 if(server_response == '0')//if ajax_check_username.php return value "0"
 { 
 $("#availability_status").html('<img src="available.png" align="absmiddle">        <font  color="Green"> Available </font>  ');
//add this image to the span with id "availability_status"
    }  
else  if(server_response == '1')//if it returns "1"
{  
 $("#availability_status").html('<img src="not_available.png"   align="absmiddle">   <font color="red">Not Available </font>');
}  

   });
   } 

  }); 

}
else
{

$("#availability_status").html('<font color="#cc0000">Username too      short</font>');
//if in case the username is less than or equal 3 characters only 
}



return false;
});

});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="content">
<form action="user_check.html" method="get">
<div>
<label for="username">Username :</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
<span id="availability_status"></span> </div>
<div>
<label for="full_name">Full Name :</label>
<input type="text" name="full_name" id="full_name"/>
</div>
<div>
<label for="email">Email&nbsp; :</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
</div>
<div>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" id="submit_btn" />
</div>
</form>
</div>

</body>

<?php 
    /* close connection */
    include 'include\closedb.php';
?> 

</html>
```

Comment: so what's your question..

Comment: I just tried to fix the formatting of your code by adding proper indentation and it appears as there might be some misplaced brackets and things. Please post what kind of problem you are having and what your browser console is reporting.

Comment: Thanks. There isn't any error message. After I type a word and leave the text box, the "loading" gif image just keeps moving and never have an available or not available image come up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your current ajax function with this

```
$.ajax({  //Make the Ajax Request
type: "POST",  
url: "ajax_check_username.php",  //file name
data: "username="+ username,  //data
success: function(server_response){        
 if($.trim(server_response) == '0')
 { 
   $("#availability_status").html('<img src="available.png" align="absmiddle">        <font  color="Green"> Available </font>  ');
 }  
 else  if($.trim(server_response) == '1')
 {  
    $("#availability_status").html('<img src="not_available.png"   align="absmiddle">     <font color="red">Not Available </font>');
 }
 else
 {
   $("#availability_status").html('Unknown response: '+server_response+' Length of string: '+server_response.length);   
 }  

}  

});
```

You don't need to do `ajaxComplete` inside the `success` function of the ajax call.

Also, it would be better to use the `blur` function instead of `change` in your case.

Comment: Thanks. I just try with your code and get  Unknown response: 0

Comment: Oh..that means there might be some trailing spaces in the response. Try out my updated code

Comment: Thanks. I just try your updated code, it shows "Checking availability..." with the gif. Seem like it cannot get the length of the string...

Comment: By the way, I have one line <meta charset="UTF-8"> in the header.php, may be this is the problem

Comment: No that won't affect the ajax response. Do you see any error in the browser console? Hit F12 and then repeat the process and see if something is printed on the console

Comment: it says "ReferenceError: server_repsonse is not defined"

Comment: My bad, I made a spelling mistake in my code (`server_repsonse.length`). Change that to `server_response.length`

Comment: I get "Unknown response: 1 Length of string: 25" now. Wow, somehow it has 25 length!?

Comment: Post your `ajax_check_username.php` code. Do it in the question itself

Comment: It is already up there. All the codes above //Here is the signup.php

Comment: No these are two different page. I just had hard time posting codes over here and don't look very clear.

Comment: Oh ok..in that case remove `header.php` from the `ajax_check_username.php`

Comment: yeah! It works now. But there is only one line <meta charset="UTF-8"> in the header.php. Why does that screw the whole thing up?

Comment: `<meta />` tag outputs to the browser. And anything that is output from `ajax_check_username.php` will be available inside `server_response`. Hence the variable `server_reponse` contained the `<meta />` tag as well as 1. And since `<meta />` tags are not visible in HTML, you couldn't see it in output

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot and I have chose this as correct answer. Have a good day.